# Use QgsRasterCalculator inside function

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I'm relatively new to PyQGIS and I'm building a plugin to perform some calculations between raster layers. I was seeking to use the QgsRasterCalculator for some operations, however, the function that I wrote return an invalid raster layer. I think the problem might be in the output path (I already printed the other parameters to make sure, and everything seems correct). The layer is not created there, and therefore the variable result does not pick it up. Do you know if there is any way to solve this?

```
def calculator(self, layers, rates100, rates5000, entries):
    formula = str(rates100[0]) + '*' + entries[0].ref + '+' + str(rates100[1]) + '*' + entries[1].ref + '+' + str(rates100[2]) + '*' + entries[2].ref + '+' + str(rates100[3]) + '*' + entries[3].ref + '+' + str(rates100[4]) + '*' + entries[4].ref + '+' + str(rates100[5]) + '*' + entries[5].ref + '+' + str(rates100[6]) + '*' + entries[6].ref + '+' + str(rates100[7]) + '*' + entries[7].ref + '+' + str(rates100[8]) + '*' + entries[8].ref
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator(formula,
                               'D:/Teste/teste.tif',
                               'GTiff',
                               layers[5].extent(),
                               layers[5].width(),
                               layers[5].height(),
                               entries)
    calc.processCalculation()
    result = QgsRasterLayer('D:/Teste/teste.tif','Vulnerabilidade')
    return result
```

Comment: So, after all, the code above works, I had to choose an existent path. The folder "Teste" wasn't created, and I thought that the QGIS was able to create it, but apperently not. Either way, I would like to know if it is possible to apply that code but without creating layers.

Comment: You will need to reimplement it in Python using logic from http://qgis.org/api/qgsrastercalculator_8cpp_source.html#l00069 IMO but I could be wrong